# how to convert &#(no); embedded in a string to a string with corresponding character in javascript?

Tags: javascript

how to convert &#(no); embedded in a string to a string with corresponding character in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
theString.replace(/&#x([0-9a-f]+);/ig, function(s, code) {
  return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(code, 16));
})
```

Similar for decimal (`&#(\d+);`).

For entities (`&copy;`) you need a look-up table.

---

Why not just directly display the string as HTML anyway? Just strip all the `<` and `>` if you want to avoid XSS.

Comment: actually i am a beginner, i am using textarea container to do html_entity_decode function, but it is not converting these spl. characters.displaying as such.

Comment: @KK: I see. In JS, `.replace` can accept a function as the replacement. If a function is provided, the arguments are feed as (1) the whole matched text (i.e. `&#xABCD;`), and (2) the 1st capture group (`ABCD`), (3) the 2nd capture group etc. Since the whole matched text is not useful, we just ignore it.

Comment: i am still having doubt,what is s and what is code?
you are mentioning so many groups , whether all are passed as array?

Comment: @KK: Do you know regular expression?